# Regular expression for line starting with a given string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I want to create a regular expression that matches input text that starts with a given word and this word may be followed by 0 or more characters(any type of character).

For example if the word is

> > **$$(hello)$$**

Will the following regular expression match the above stated requirements:

> > **^\$\$\(hello\)\$\$.***

Comment: should do, why, havn't you tried it?

Comment: Have you tried that?  Yes, that would work, but keep in mind it wouldn't be capturing anything since you don't have any un-escaped parens (if you need that functionality).

Comment: Just test it, [it works](http://regexr.com?30421).

Comment: Why not just use `^\$\$\(hello\)\$\$` since you're checking for start of text only.

Comment: Yeah it works in regexpal.com. There was actually some mistake in my code and thats why it was not matching. I want to match special characters like $,?,%, (,] etc. and thats why I need to escape such special characters. Also without .* in the end of regexp, I think it would only match text which starts with the word and is not followed by other characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here: http://regexpal.com/

You can test out what will and won't work. Great for testing out regex quickly. What you wrote will work with your example, but I would run it through some more tests to be sure.